# getting input value from user in jdk 1.8.0 compiler

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

[image]I'm using jdk 1.8.0 compiler to get the integer value from user.But it shows exception.If i use other compilers it works.Why jdk 1.8.0 compiler shows exception?

```
Scanner myInput = new Scanner( System.in );
      int a;
      int b;
      int sum;
      System.out.print( "Enter first integer: " );
      a = myInput.nextInt();
      System.out.print( "Enter second integer: " );
      b = myInput.nextInt();
      sum = a + b;
      System.out.printf( "Sum = %d\n", sum );
```

It shows the exception Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException.The link of the compiler which i am using https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: Runs perfectly on java 1.8 here. Can you post the exact stacktrace?

Comment: Please follow this guideline when you ask a question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Give some context. At least good chunk of stack trace that could make sense, put here. What're the tools, you're using to compile this ? How did you compile this ? I can't find anything in this given snippet that only specific to Java 8.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: Type 2 numbers in STDIN tab in separate lines.

Comment: @Ghost The images are kinda necessary for context of CodingGround platform

Comment: @cricket_007 Well. The mcve thing leads to ask: what are the inputs you are using. Does it really matter that they go into the STDIN tab?! The problem is most likely due to invalid input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the "STDIN" tab next to the "Source file"

Type your numbers in there.

Answer (score 0):

It probably has to do with the fact that you have to enter your stdin arguments prior to running the code in the codingground editor. If you don't, it won't ask you for input but just throws the exception based on an empty stream.

[image: Example]